# What is the "buffer" in the Atom editor?

Tags: atom-editor

In describing how find (& find and replace) work, the [Atom Flight Manual](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/find-and-replace/) refers to the *buffer* as one scope of search, with the entire project being another scope. What is the buffer? It seems like it would be the current file, but I expect it is more than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Atom Flight Manual](https://flight-manual.atom.io/resources/sections/glossary/#buffer):

> A buffer is the text content of a file in Atom. It's basically the same as a file for most descriptions, but it's the version Atom has in memory. For instance, you can change the text of a buffer and it isn't written to its associated file until you save it.

Also came across this from [*The Craft of Text Editing* by Craig Finseth, Chapter 6](http://web.mit.edu/%7Eyandros/doc/craft-text-editing/Chapter-6.html):

> A buffer is the basic unit of text being edited. It can be any size, from zero characters to the largest item that can be manipulated on the computer system. This limit on size is usually set by such factors as address space, amount of real and/or virtual memory, and mass storage capacity. A buffer can exist by itself, or it can be associated with at most one file. When associated with a file, the buffer is a copy of the contents of the file at a specific time. A file, on the other hand, can be associated with any number of buffers, each one being a copy of that file's contents at the same or at different times.

Comment: Nice answer. I should have found that myself. Thanks!